# Permutations of $[n]$ with $k$ peaks

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is there a formula for the number of permutations of $[n]$ with $k$ peaks?

Here is some information on the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=16,88,16&language=english&go=Search) about these numbers, but no such formula is given. I'm sure such a formula exists due to the following question posed in Miklós Bóna's book, [Combinatorics of Permutations](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Op-nF-mBR7YC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=permutations%20of%20%5Bn%5D%20with%20k%20peaks&source=bl&ots=hR9iwItomh&sig=eVUwd4lnL06SgiS7mR3Rq-p9WcM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=okmZUaCWHKiC4ATZ_ICgCA&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=permutations%20of%20%5Bn%5D%20with%20k%20peaks&f=false) (p.40, Q.33). Unfortunately the Google book is only a preview and the required solutions are missing.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I understand that an element $a_k$ of a permutation $[n]=123\cdots n$ is called a *peak* when $a_{k-1}<a_k$ and $a_k>a_{k+1}$. We define $a_0=a_{n+1}=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a recurrence relation for these numbers by defining the numbers $a_{nk}^{\pm\pm}$, where the first sign is $+$ for permutations beginning with a peak and $-$ otherwise, and the second sign likewise for ending with a peak. Thus, for instance, $a_{nk}^{++}$ counts the number of permutations of $[n]$ with $k$ peaks that begin and end with a peak. (Clearly $a_{nk}^{+-}=a_{nk}^{-+}$.) Then by considering the possible places in which you can insert $n+1$ in a permutation of $[n]$ you get

$$
a_{n+1,k}^{++}=\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_{ij}^{+-}a_{n-i,k-1-j}^{-+}+2\sum_{j=0}^ka_{ij}^{++}a_{n-i,k-j}^{-+}+\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}a_{ij}^{++}a_{n-i,k+1-j}^{++}\right)
$$

and similar relations for $a_{n+1,k}^{-+}$ and $a_{n+1,k}^{--}$, with suitable initial and boundary conditions.